# Implementation of a lock-free fixed-sized allocator - follow-up - with commented code

Tags: c++, c++11, multithreading, memory-management, lock-free

The following implementation of a lock-free fixed-size allocator is a follow-up of:

[Implementation of a lock-free fixed-sized allocator](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/105656/implementation-of-a-lock-free-fixed-sized-allocator)

---

### §1 - Introduction

The purpose is self-learning of atomic types and synchronization. I would appreciate a review that does any of the following (from most important to least):

- Verification of assumption 2 in **§3.1**.
- Finds issues.
- Touches upon the efficiency of the code.

The previous version had many issues that were kindly pointed out by both answers.

### §2 - Allocator implementation

This implementation now contains alignment for the data and alignment to make sure that highly contested variables aren't on the same cache line which provided a substantial performance improvement.

#### §2.1 - Function description

**§2.1.1 - Verification function: `try_decrease_available_blocks()`**

Checks that if there are any available blocks for `allocate()`. It's purpose is to atomically compare `num_avail_blocks_` with 0 and decrease `num_avail_blocks_` by 1 of it is not equal to 0.

This is required, since fetch/sub operations would cause it to underflow on their own.

**§2.1.2 - Allocation function: `allocate()`**

Checks that there are available blocks by calling `try_decrease_available_blocks()`. This condition assures that only `capacity` (maximum capacity specified in the constructor) calls actually go through to the next part.

Inside a CAS loop, the `next_alloc_offset_` tag is increased by one to prevent the ABA issue. The pointer to be returned `p_block` is then obtained by the offset that was in `next_alloc_offset_`'s `value` data member.

The new allocation offset is then set to the value at the first `sizeof(size_type)` bytes of `p_block`. The CAS operation then takes place.

**§2.1.3 - Deallocation function: `deallocate(pointer)`**

Since `allocate()` returns unique pointers to every caller, then every pointer argument p received by `deallocate()` is unique. We calculate the deallocated pointer's offset starting from the initial memory location at `p_memory_` as that will be the value of `next_allocation_offset_.value`.

In a CAS loop, the new allocation offset's tag is decreased to prevent the ABA problem and `p`'s next offset is set to the current `next_allocation_offset_.value` value before `next_allocation_offset_` is updated.

The number of available blocks is then incremented and `allocate()` can now be called one more time.

#### §2.2 - Implementation

```
#ifndef OAG_LOCK_FREE_MEMORY_CHUNK_H
#define OAG_LOCK_FREE_MEMORY_CHUNK_H

#pragma warning( disable : 4324 ) // ignore alignof(n) warning

#include <type_traits>
#include <atomic>

namespace oag
{
    template <typename T, std::size_t cache_line_size = 128>
    class lock_free_memory_chunk
    {
    private:
        template <typename Tag, typename Value, std::size_t lock_free_max_size>
        struct tagged_value // change
        {
            static_assert( sizeof( Tag ) + sizeof( Value ) <= lock_free_max_size,
                "sizeof(tagged_value) > lock_free_max_size : cannot be lock-free" );
            Tag tag;
            Value value;
        };

    public:
        using value_type = T;
        using pointer = value_type*;
        using size_type = std::size_t;

    private:
        // determines the type of memory allocated to preserve alignment of
        // the biggest type between `value_type` and `size_type`;
        // we only need the biggest of either to store its associated `next` offset
        // at the first sizeof(size_type) bytes of each block.
        using block_t = std::conditional_t<
            sizeof( value_type ) < sizeof( size_type ), size_type, value_type>;

        using byte = unsigned char;
        using tagged_value_t = tagged_value<size_type, size_type, 8>;

    public:
        explicit lock_free_memory_chunk( size_type const );
        ~lock_free_memory_chunk();

        // TODO: deal with copy & move operations

        pointer allocate() noexcept;
        void deallocate( pointer ) noexcept;

    private:
        bool try_decrease_available_blocks() noexcept;

    private:
        block_t* p_memory_;
        alignas( cache_line_size ) std::atomic<size_type> num_avail_blocks_;
        alignas( cache_line_size ) std::atomic<tagged_value_t> next_alloc_offset_;
    };
}

namespace oag
{
    template <typename T, std::size_t cache_line_size>
    lock_free_memory_chunk<T, cache_line_size>::lock_free_memory_chunk( size_type const capacity ) :
        p_memory_{ new block_t[ capacity ] },
        num_avail_blocks_{ capacity },
        next_alloc_offset_{ { 0, 0 } }
    {
        size_type i{ 0 };
        for ( block_t* p{ p_memory_ }; i < capacity; ++p )
        {
            // assign offset to next block at first sizeof(size_type) bytes
            // i.e.
            // offset:      [ 1 ][ 2 ][ 3 ]...[ N + 1 ]
            // location:    [ 0 ][ 1 ][ 2 ]...[ N ]
            *reinterpret_cast<size_type*>( p ) = ++i;
        }
    }

    template <typename T, std::size_t cache_line_size>
    inline
    lock_free_memory_chunk<T, cache_line_size>::~lock_free_memory_chunk()
    {
        delete[] p_memory_;
    }

    template <typename T, std::size_t cache_line_size>
    inline typename lock_free_memory_chunk<T, cache_line_size>::pointer
    lock_free_memory_chunk<T, cache_line_size>::allocate() noexcept
    {
        // can we decrement the number of available blocks down to 0 or greater
        // IFF it is not already 0; in other words, assure we have available blocks
        if ( !try_decrease_available_blocks() )
        {
            // no free blocks: cannot allocate -> return nullptr
            return nullptr;
        }

        tagged_value_t alloc_offset = next_alloc_offset_.load();
        pointer p_block{ nullptr };
        tagged_value_t new_next_alloc_offset;
        do
        {
            // increase the id tag to prevent the ABA problem
            new_next_alloc_offset.tag = alloc_offset.tag + 1;

            // cast to pointer to `T`
            p_block = reinterpret_cast<pointer>( p_memory_ + alloc_offset.value );

            // set the next alloc offset to the `size_type` value contained
            // in the first `sizeof(size_type)` bytes of this block
            new_next_alloc_offset.value = *reinterpret_cast<size_type*>( p_block );
        }
        while ( !next_alloc_offset_.compare_exchange_strong(
            alloc_offset, new_next_alloc_offset ) );

        return p_block;
    }

    template <typename T, std::size_t cache_line_size>
    inline void
    lock_free_memory_chunk<T, cache_line_size>::deallocate( pointer p ) noexcept
    {
        tagged_value_t alloc_offset_from_p = next_alloc_offset_.load();
        tagged_value_t new_next_alloc_offset;

        // calculate the next allocation offset based on argument `p`
        // this will be a value between 0 and N, where N is total capacity
        new_next_alloc_offset.value = static_cast<size_type>(
            reinterpret_cast<block_t*>( p ) - p_memory_ );
        do
        {
            // decrease the id tag to prevent the ABA problem
            new_next_alloc_offset.tag = alloc_offset_from_p.tag - 1;

            // set the next alloc offset of block `p` to the current alloc offset
            *reinterpret_cast<size_type*>( p ) = alloc_offset_from_p.value;
        }
        while ( !next_alloc_offset_.compare_exchange_strong(
            alloc_offset_from_p, new_next_alloc_offset ) );

        num_avail_blocks_.fetch_add( 1 );
    }

    template <typename T, std::size_t cache_line_size>
    inline bool
    lock_free_memory_chunk<T, cache_line_size>::try_decrease_available_blocks() noexcept
    {
        auto n = num_avail_blocks_.load();
        do
        {
            // if the number of available blocks is 0
            if ( n == 0 )
            {
                // true: there are no available blocks -> return false
                return false;
            }
        } // false: decrease the number by 1
        while ( !num_avail_blocks_.compare_exchange_strong( n, n - 1 ) );
        // false: there is at least one available block -> return true
        return true;
    }
}
#endif // !OAG_LOCK_FREE_MEMORY_CHUNK_H
```

### §3 - Solving the ABA problem

The purpose of the `tagged_value<Tag, Value>` class is to prevent the ABA problem by associating a tag with a value (and vice-versa). It is a nested class inside the actual allocator (shown above).

It is to be used as the template argument of `std::atomic<T>`. It will be lock free as long as the combined size of its template arguments is `<= N`; where `N` is the maximum supported size for `std::atomic<tagged_value<Tag, Value, N>>` implementations to be lock free.

```
template <typename Tag, typename Value, std::size_t required_size_for_lock_free>
struct tagged_value // change
{
    static_assert( sizeof( Tag ) + sizeof( Value ) <= required_size_for_lock_free,
        "sizeof(tagged_value) > required_size_for_lock_free : cannot be lock-free" );
    Tag tag;
    Value value;
};
```

#### §3.1 - Assumptions

1. For the allocator, the tag and the value are both `size_type`. The tag is increased/decreased atomically when there is an allocation/deallocation. Since the allocator's size is fixed and that the tag is of the same type, there is no possibility for the ABA problem to occur due to underflow/overflow of the tag.
2. The only possibility for the `tagged_value` to be equal to another `tagged_value` is if for `N` allocations, there are `N` deallocations done in the reverse order (of addresses). `N` deallocations done in a non-reversed order will simply cause the `tagged_value` to differ on the `tag` and/or `value` member, and the CAS will fail as required. In the case that a `tagged_value` is equal to another, we can treat it as if no allocations/deallocations were actually done while the original thread was paused and the CAS operation thus succeeds without issue.

#### §4 - Sample tests

The following test calculates a grand average over the number of executions given to the `run_test(memory_chunk, n)`'s `n` parameter. The memory chunk can have a cache line size specified as its second argument in order to make it customizable for different processors. It is set to 128 by default.

It also verifies that the `allocate()` function does not give out the same address twice by comparing every address it gives out to every thread together.

```
#include <unordered_set>
#include <future>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include "lock_free_memory_chunk.h"

template <typename MemoryChunk>
using mc_pointer_set_t = std::unordered_set<typename MemoryChunk::pointer>;

auto num_threads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency() - 1;
std::size_t const num_blocks_per_thread = 10000;

template <typename MemoryChunk>
decltype( auto ) call_alloc_and_dealloc( MemoryChunk& mc, std::size_t n, long long& execution_time_ms )
{
    mc_pointer_set_t<MemoryChunk> mcps;
    mcps.reserve( n );

    auto time_begin = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i )
        mcps.insert( mc.allocate() );

    for ( auto* p : mcps )
        mc.deallocate( p );

    auto time_end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    mcps.clear();

    execution_time_ms =
        std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>( time_end - time_begin ).count();
    return mcps;
}

template <typename MemoryChunk>
void check_sets( mc_pointer_set_t<MemoryChunk> const& s1, mc_pointer_set_t<MemoryChunk> const& s2 )
{
    auto end = std::cend( s2 );
    for ( auto* p : s1 )
        if ( s2.find( p ) != end )
            throw std::exception( "two sets have the same address" );
}

template <typename MemoryChunk>
void run_test( MemoryChunk& mc, unsigned int K )
{
    std::vector<long long> execution_times( num_threads );
    long long avg = 0;
    for ( decltype( num_threads ) k{ 0 }; k < K; ++k )
    {
        std::vector<std::future<mc_pointer_set_t<MemoryChunk>>> v;
        for ( decltype( num_threads ) i{ 0 }; i < num_threads; ++i )
        {
            v.emplace_back( std::async(
                std::launch::async,
                call_alloc_and_dealloc<MemoryChunk>,
                std::ref( mc ),
                num_blocks_per_thread,
                std::ref( execution_times[ i ] ) ) );
        }
        for ( auto& t : v )
        {
            t.wait();
        }

        for ( decltype( num_threads ) i = 0; i < num_threads; ++i )
        {
            //std::cout << "Execution time for thread " << i << ": " << execution_times[ i ] << " ms\n";
            avg += execution_times[ i ];
        }

        std::vector<mc_pointer_set_t<MemoryChunk>> comparisons;
        for ( decltype( num_threads ) i{ 0 }; i < num_threads; ++i )
        {
            comparisons.emplace_back( std::move( v[ i ].get() ) );
        }

        std::vector<std::future<void>> exceptions;
        for ( decltype( num_threads ) i{ 0 }; i < num_threads; ++i )
        {
            for ( decltype( num_threads ) j{ i + 1 }; j < num_threads; ++j )
            {
                exceptions.emplace_back( std::async(
                    std::launch::async,
                    check_sets<MemoryChunk>,
                    std::ref( comparisons[ i ] ),
                    std::ref( comparisons[ j ] ) ) );
            }
        }
        for ( auto& f : exceptions )
        {
            f.get();
        }
    }
    std::cout << "Average execution time: " << avg / execution_times.size() << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    oag::lock_free_memory_chunk<int, 128> mc128{ num_blocks_per_thread * num_threads };
    std::cout << "BEGIN: mc128 tests\n";
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
        run_test( mc128, 100 );
    std::cout << "END:   mc128 tests\n\n";

    oag::lock_free_memory_chunk<int, 32> mc32{ num_blocks_per_thread * num_threads };
    std::cout << "BEGIN: mc32 tests\n";
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
        run_test( mc32, 100 );
    std::cout << "END:   mc32 tests\n";
}
```